# Does any one know this Napster House Track I once found?

Tags: electronic-music, house

I am looking for a house track that appeared on Napster from 1997-98 that was titled as 'Midnight Breeze' by Jazz N Groove or Bobby and Steve. The track would be 120-135 bmp and had a jazzy feel to it.

Possibly a white label and mis-labeled with this group/title as I have research the duo.